# How can I make Symfony serialize empty associative arrays as empty JSON objects?

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I need to serialize a set of PHP associative arrays to JSON using Symfony. Some of these arrays happen to be empty.

This means that all arrays containing data will be serialized to JSON objects whereas all empty arrays will be serialized to JSON empty arrays. Since I would like to avoid having to check whether something is an object or an array, I would prefer if all my arrays (empty or not) would be serialized to JSON objects, not arrays.

How can I achieve this with Symfony 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symfony 2 allows you to pass a context to the serializer in which you can set serialization options. I could not find this in the official documentation but saw it while looking through the source code.

In order to serialize empty PHP arrays to empty JSON objects you need to pass a flag to `json_encode` (which is what the Symfony JSON encoder uses). You can pass arbitrary flags, basically all the options that [`json_encode`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) accepts.

It works like this:

```
$serializer->serialize($myObject, "json", ["json_encode_options" => JSON_FORCE_OBJECT])
```

Comment: but if $myObject has also good array like ['lol', 'foo'] than it will be converted to ugly {"0": "lol", "1": "foo"}

Comment: @errogaht Indeed, but that is not an associative array.

Comment: The ideal solution would be:
1. Serialize empty arrays to {}
2. Serialize not empty true arrays to arrays [1,2,3,4]
3. one piece of code for all types in app
but i think it's impossible :(

Answer (score -1):

Since Symfony 4.4 there is a new option `preserve_empty_objects` that helps you - if you can convert the empty array into an empty object first:

```
$array = ['foo' => new stdClass()];
$serializer->serialize($array, "json", ["preserve_empty_objects" => true]);
// {'foo': {}}
```